# Specify schema/instance for DB2 query in connection string

Tags: c#, db2

I am trying to specify the default schema/instance as part of a connection string (or specific command) so it does not need to be part of the query.

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}; Database=myDB; Hostname=myHostName; Port=myPort; Protocol=TCPIP; Uid=myID; Pwd=myPW;");
OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand("select count(*) from customers", conn);
conn.Open();
var value = comm.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();
```

Unfortunately this fails with the error:

> ERROR [42S02] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0204N **myID**.customers is an undefined name. SQLSTATE=42704.

Notice it's using **myID** where the Schema/Instance should be. If I specify the schema/instance explicity:

```
OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand("select count(*) from mySCHEMA.customers", conn);
```

it works as expected. I'd like to specify `mySCHEMA` as part of the Connection String, similar to "Initial Catalog" when using MS SQL Server.

After a bunch of experimentation and googling, I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, this one was obvious. I just need `CurrentSchema=mySCHEMA` in the connection string.

For some reason I didn't connect that dot right away after working through http://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2 (tried all sorts of variations like Schema, Default Schema, etc). Hopefully this helps someone in the future...